# Can Groovy/Java implicitly cast to subclasses (or have custom implicit casts)?

Tags: java, types, groovy, casting

I'm using MongoDB with Groovy + Grails on top. While the MongoDB Java API is sinfully verbose, Groovy helps in this regard by being able to write HashMaps like so:

```
def map = [foo: "bar", one: "two"]
```

In MongoDB, objects are added to the database as BasicDBObjects, which extend HashMap, so I can write something like this in Groovy:

```
things.save([ foo: "bar" ] as BasicDBObject)
```

While I don't know where the BasicDBOBject cast is coming from (is it built-in because BasicDBObject already inherits from HashMap?), it would be splendid if I didn't have to add the explicit cast every time I want to persist an object.

Does Groovy/Java have a way of making superclass-subclass casts implicit, or at least defining custom implicit casts as to avoid using the as operator everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are on Groovy, why not some metaprogramming? :-)

```
things.metaClass.save = { Map map -> delegate.save( map as BasicDBObject ) }
```

The idea is simple: we add a new method on `things` object, which is a save() method that receives a Map and redirect the call to the `things.save(BasicDBObject)` casting accordingly.

If you want, you can add this method directly to the thing's class:

```
ThingsClass.metaClass.save = { Map map -> delegate.save( map as BasicDBObject ) }
```

I wrote the following script trying to simulate what you described, i hope i got it right:

```
class BasicDBObject extends HashMap { }

class Mongo {
    def save(BasicDBObject obj) {
        println "saving $obj"
    }
}

def mongo = new Mongo()

// here it will fail
try {
    mongo.save uno:1, dos:2
    assert false
} catch (e) { }


mongo.metaClass.save = { Map map -> delegate.save( map as BasicDBObject ) }

// and here it succeeds ;-)
mongo.save uno:1, dos:2
```

Also note that it doesn't need square brackets neither parens. The colon gives away the map thing

For the `as` method, which is an operator that can be overloaded through the `.asType(Class)`, i believe it works because it tries to instantiate a new `BasicDBObject` passing the map as a parameter in the constructor. It can be found around line 316 in the following link:

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java

Comment: Yes! This is a much more elegant way to do it. I actually spontaneously thought of this metaprogramming approach long after I asked the question, but it seems to have leaked out of my memory until now.